# Obtener el valor de una celda de un DataGrid wpf

Tags: wpf

Como puedo obtener el valor de una celda de un DataGrid (WPF). Tengo esto:

```
     DataRowView item = (DGContactos as DataGrid).SelectedItem as DataRowView;  
    _contacto.Nombre = item.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();  
    _contacto.NumeroCelular = item.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();  
    _contacto.NumeroTrabajo = item.Row.ItemArray[2].ToString();  
    _contacto.NumeroParticular = item.Row.ItemArray[3].ToString();  
    _contacto.Email = item.Row.ItemArray[4].ToString();  
    _contacto.Notas = item.Row.ItemArray[5].ToString();
```

Eso trabaja bien y me da todos los valores.

Aparte quiero saber el valor especifico de la celda que recibe el foco ejemplo: string valorCelda = DGContactos....

He probado varas maneras y tengo varios dias buscando en la red y solo encuentro para DataDridView.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas. No sabia que las tenia ya que no me llego email que notificara de las mismas.
Ya había resuelto ubicando el índice y luego "como lo tengo en la pregunta" en "ItemArray[i]" obtengo el valor y lo retorno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
DataRowView view = (DataRowView)my_datagrid.SelectedItem;
int index = my_datagrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
string cellvalue = view.Row.ItemArray[index].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para eso tienes que capturar el evento de selección del DataGrid y poner que el modo de selección solo sea por celda.

Aquí la grid en XALM:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" SelectedCellsChanged="dg_SelectedCellsChanged" SelectionUnit="Cell">
```

Y aquí el envento:

```
 private void dg_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IList<DataGridCellInfo> celdas = e.AddedCells;
        string valor = celdas[0].Item as string;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría que no captures directamente el valor de la celda salvo que tengas un motivo muy especial para ello, sino que trabajes siempre con la colección que tienes detrás del DataGrid.

Por ejemplo, si tenemos:

```
public class Coches {
    string marca;
    string modelo;
}

Coche coche = new Coche();
ObservableCollection<Coches> listaCoches = new ObservableCollection<Coche>();
```

Y en tu DataGrid tienes:

```
<DataGrid ItemSource="{Binding listaCoches}" SelectedItem="{Binding coche}"/>
```

Yo lo que haría es mirar coche.marca o coche.modelo, en vez de mirar lo que hay en la celda correspondiente a la columna modelo o marca.

Suele ser mejor mirar la colección que está detrás del DataGrid, que las propias celdas. No obstante, si lo que quieres es ver la propia celda, siempre puedes mirar el evento CellEditEnding, donde tienes un objeto llamado "e.EditingElement" (e.EditingElement.DataContext si quieres todo la fila) que tiene todo lo que necesitas, pero insisto en que te recomiendo mucho más la otra aproximación.

Finalmente, y quizá sea lo que más te interesa, está el evento CurrentCellChanged, desde el que puedes capturar lo que buscas con:

```
DataGrid miDataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
miDataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex
```

Y sabiendo la columna en la que está posicionado, te puedes ir a listaCoches y mirar el valor de esa propiedad.